# Microsoft Defender SmartScreen Edge marked our site as phishing site

Tags: microsoft-edge, unsafe, phishing, smartscreen, microsoft365-defender

Our domain, [vstbalance.com](https://vstbalance.com), was flagged as phishing by Microsoft Defender SmartScreen. After switching to [portal.vstbalance.com](https://portal.vstbalance.com) (which targets the same folder), the issue was resolved. How can we determine the specific actions that triggered the phishing label on Microsoft Edge?
#phishing.
#MicrosoftDefenderSmartScreen

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by the Microsoft support team. They don't respond about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-security-smartscreen#site-analysis) to learn how Microsoft Defender SmartScreen determines whether a site is potentially malicious. In short:

- Analyzing visited webpages for indications of suspicious behavior.
- Checking the visited sites against a dynamic record of reported
  phishing sites.

If you need to report this site as safe, in the warning page, you should click More information --> Report that this site doesn’t contain phishing threats. This will take you to a feedback page where you can send feedback to the Microsoft Defender Team.

Comment: Kendrick Li Thanks for your feed back. 
I have try the feedback method it but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @MuhammadNauman You may need to wait for the Team to review your feedback.

Comment: This is happening for more than three months

Comment: The issue is resolved by the Microsoft support team.